# Refresh problems with X11 software with WSL2

Tags: wsl2, wslg

I've been running ubuntu 22.04 LTS on wsl2 on Windows 11 pro for a couple of months. I was able to successfully run gnuplot, gimp and xmgrace but, all of a sudden, I got refresh problems when I click any menu of xmgrace, gimp or run gnuplot and move the focus to an other window. Everything in the gnuplot gets blurred. The same happens with the menus of gimp or xmgrace, as is exemplified below.

[image: Blurred menu]

Any ideas? Thanks!

This is the output I got from `wsl --version`

```
WSL version: 2.0.9.0 
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1 
WSLg Version: 1.0.59 
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D Version: 1.611.1-81528511 
DXCore Version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp 
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2715
```

This is my /etc/wsl.conf:

```
# Automatically mount Windows drive when the distribution is launched
[automount]

# Sets the `/etc/fstab` file to be processed when a WSL distribution is launched.
mountFsTab = true

[network]
generateHosts = false

[boot]
systemd=true
```

Comment: We’ll need more diagnostic information. WSL kernel version, Windows version, ect.

Comment: This is the output I got from wsl --version:

WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg Version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D Version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore Version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2715

Comment: Well probably need .wslconfig so we know how your WSLg environment is defined

Comment: As far as I understood from google, the .wslconfig file should be in C:\Users\Username, but it is not there. I guess that might be my problem... Is there a model that I could adapt to my setup?

Comment: Following 

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/wsl/blob/main/WSL/wsl-config.md, I created a .wslconfig file with the following entry (which seems to make sense to me): guiApplications=true

Comment: It seems to work properly now! Thanks!

Comment: You should submit an detailed answer instead of answering your own question with a comment.

Comment: I am not sure that I found the solution. I ran into the same problems after rebooting the computer... By the way, what do you mean by submitting a detailed answer? Should I click on the button "Answer your question"?

Answer (score 0):

> Following [WSL Config file documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/wsl/blob/main/WSL/wsl-config.md), I created a `.wslconfig` file with the following entry: `guiApplications=true`