# google-chrome when ran from Ubuntu / WSL gives weird visual glitches

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wslg

I'm working on a fresh install of Windows (Windows 11; 22H2 OS Build 22621.2715). I enabled WSL, installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 from the Microsoft App store and then did the following in Ubuntu:

```
get https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -f install
```

Now, when I type in `google-chrome` in Ubuntu, this is what I get:

[image]

Clearly that's not a usable install.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest to upgrade to Windows 11 23H2 - WSL graphics were supposedly improved.

Comment: Create the configuration file as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1817783/refresh-problems-with-x11-software-with-wsl2)