# Display drivers down

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, windows-11

I have a blurry screen when I install Ubuntu on my windows 11. I found out that my display drivers shows some error. I have removed it with DDU and reinstall another one but still the problem persists. I found out that in the process of install Ubuntu, checking the virtual machine platform in the Turn Windows Feature on or off is the cause.

How do I solve this blurry screen. I need Ubuntu to finish up my final project too.

Comment: Do I understand correctly the Ubuntu System to be a Hyper-V VM?  If so, for best results, it is usually best to be a Generation 2 VM with Integration services enabled.

Comment: So is virtual machine platform turned on or off? It’s certainly compatible with a Hyper-V VM. Provide your WSLg configuration file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh problems with X11 software with WSL2](https://superuser.com/questions/1817783/refresh-problems-with-x11-software-with-wsl2)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1823280/google-chrome-when-ran-from-ubuntu-wsl-gives-weird-visual-glitches)

Comment: Make a Ubuntu Live USB, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview, and run directly from USB without need to install. If you want to keep information and changes over a few session, make it *persistent*, https://www.howtogeek.com/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/, with the *caveat* that a fast USB device must be used, or the OS will be *slow*.